# How to call a fileupload in Dropbox using CURL correctly?

Tags: java, curl, dropbox

I have the following mapping:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("filePath") String filePath) throws Exception {
    dropboxService.uploadFile(file, filePath);
    return "You successfully uploaded " + filePath + "!!";
}
```

When I try for example:

```
curl --data "file=/Users/admin/Documents/sun.jpg&&filepath=/a" localhost:8080/dropbox/upload
```

I get the `500 Error - current request is not a  multipart request`
How can I call that correctly using CURL?

Answer (score 0):

For file upload:

```
curl --form "fileupload=@filename.txt" http://hostname/resource
```

Comment: But I need to include the params file and filepath!

Comment: to get the file path use this: file.path

Comment: but if you need to send both file and filepath, you need to create a DTO with all fields you want (MultipartFile file, String filePath) and change your controller arguments with @ResponseBody Dto dto and use CRUL like this: curl --data "file=@filename.txt&filePath=path" http://hostname/resource